# Copying from multiple text input boxes to a text area:

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have 4 input text fields which I want to have them copy to a text area, I have tried to do the same as make each copy to a seperate text input field, but that did not work.

My code is as follows:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Page Message:</legend>
        <div class="textarey">
        <input type="text" class="lookalike" id="message_text1" name="message_text1" onkeyup="copy_data(this);  if(this.value.length>=24) document.editPage.message_text2.focus()" style="text-decoration:ltr;" value="<?php echo $page['message_text']; ?>" size="38" maxlength="24"><br>

        <input type="text" id="message_text2" name="message_text2" maxlength="24" size="38" class="lookalike"  style="text-decoration:ltr;"  value="<?php echo $page['message_text']; ?>" onkeyup="copy_data(this); if(this.value.length>=24) document.editPage.message_text3.focus()"><br>

        <input type="text" id="message_text3" name="message_text3" maxlength="24" size="38" class="lookalike"  style="text-decoration:ltr;"   value="<?php echo $page['message_text']; ?>" onkeyup="copy_data(this);  if(this.value.length>=24) document.editPage.message_text4.focus()"><br>

        <input type="text" id="message_text4" name="message_text4" size="42" class="lookalike"  style="text-decoration:ltr;"  value="<?php echo $page['message_text']; ?>" onkeyup="copy_data(this)">
 </div>


      <textarea id="message" /><?php echo $page['message']; ?></textarea>
```

And the Javascript that copies from the fields is here:

```
   function copy_data(val){ 
        var messageText = document.getElementById(val.id).value 
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = messageText;


}
```

My issue is that every time a textfield gets to the end of it's maxchars it clears the text area. Anyone have any ideas here?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you don't stuff **all** your style in your classes?  It would at least reduce your code slightly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = "";
  for(var x=1;x<=4;x++) {
     text += document.getElementById("message_text"+x).value;
     text += "\n";
  }
  document.getElementById("message").value = text;
</script>
```

- you might consider making a function for copying from whatever input you want into 
  whatever element.

Comment: Is it possible to pass a styling from a piexe if selected input into the text area to which I am copting the inputted text? I Have this:
`function formatText(el,tag){
var selectedText = document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);// IE:Moz
if (selectedText == "")
{return false}
var newText='#'+tag+''+selectedText+'#'+tag+'';
if(document.selection){    //IE
document.selection.createRange().text=newText;
}
else{
el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+newText+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);
}
}`

Answer (score 2):

```
function copy_data(val){ 
    var messageText = document.getElementById(val.id).value 
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += messageText;
}
```

But I recommend against using inline js.

Comment: Looks great, the only question I have, is how you will call the function from the input? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't fully get your question as such - 'how will you call the function from the input'?? From whatever I can make out from your question, you seem to be asking as to how will the function be called. Um, that depends upon how #user1395580 wants to call it. All I did was to change the '=' sign to '+=' sign - which would do the work. Btw, i recommend the code given in the above answer. It's much better than what I've done.

Answer (score -1):

> My issue is that every time a textfield gets to the end of it's
>   maxchars it clears the text area. Anyone have any ideas here?

This is because even when you reach the end of maxchar you still keep typing. As per your javascript function, at a time, textarea will show data only from one of the 4 textfields. So, the movement field1 reaches max length, field2 gains focus as per your code.

```
onkeyup="copy_data(this);  if(this.value.length>=24) document.editPage.message_text2.focus()"
```

So, as field2 gains focus, and you keep typing, your textarea becomes blank and start showing field2 data.